# REST: Filter List Items by Content Type Name

Tags: 2013, rest, content-type

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with this URL:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + String.format("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{0}')/items?$select=ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$filter=ContentType/Name eq 'Highlight Report'", documentsListTitle)
```

I get

> 400 (Bad Request)

Note I'm specifically looking for a REST solution with an example if possible.

Comment: getbytitle('{0}') ? I thought there should be the listname...

Comment: Notice the use of `String.format`.

Comment: To the close voters: The question is regarding **REST** API not server side or client side using C#. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found a way which works for me. SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

**Starting point:**

A document library with two content types `Document` & `Highlight Report` and two documents in it for testing purpose.

[image]

**REST URL:**

The REST URL for filtering only the document with the content type `Document` is:

```
https://<yourdomain>/_api/lists/getbytitle('<yourlistname>')/items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Document'
```

The output is:

[image]

If you want to get the document `lorem1` which is content type `Highlight Report` the REST URL looks like this:

```
https://<yourdomain>/_api/lists/getbytitle('<yourlistname>')/items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Highlight Report'
```

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Just tried this and I get back a zero length array, which probably means no items were returned, which means the filter isn't working (I should get two items).

Comment: What is the name of the library and of the content type? Could you try to get first all your items with /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LIBRARYNAME')/items

Comment: Yes using that URL `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items` I get back all the items from the list. But when I add `?$filter=startswith(ContentType,'Highlight Report')` I get back nothing.

Comment: Tried it. You are right! But I think it is because of the blank between Highlight and Report. Try adding the default content type Document, upload a document with that content type and try the REST URL like this: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=startswith(ContentType,'Document')

Comment: I just created a content type called SuperHighlightReport without spaces and it worked.

Comment: But shouldn't the use of `startswith` mean that if I use this `$filter=startswith(ContentType,'Highlight')` I should get back the correct result? But I don't..

Comment: Tried it now with a new content type called "Super Report" and the REST URL /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=startswith(ContentType,'Super Report') worked... You can try creating a complete new content type, one e.G. "Testreport" and another with "Test Report" and try the REST-Call again. For me it is working...

Comment: But further up you said you tried it and it didn't work. But now it's working for you. So what was the difference? Regardless, I need a solution that works with the "Highlight Report" content type that already exists. Many thanks for your help though.

Comment: I know, pretty strange. The URL /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Highlight Report' is also working for me. Updated my answer with this REST URL

Comment: That worked! Can't believe the solution was staring us right in the face. So simple in the end. It doesn't make sense to me because `ContentType` usually needs to be expanded. Anyway, this is my preferred solution. Thanks Patrick :)

Comment: Filtering on content type name also works for me without the use of CAML. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with english pictures and the content type you are using.

Comment: @HarryB it seems it is not necessary to expand ContentType, as proven by Patrick. Still confused why...

Comment: This is very strange, but thank you for going through all the random SharePoint oddities for me.

Comment: Working for me as well. You may need to add some reserved characters if your content type name contains "spaces" for instance.

Answer (score 4):

`$filter` by `ContentType` is not supported. Reason could be `ContentType` is not any column of list **OR** Microsoft does not support it yet. `$expand` is supported.

Ignore the `&$filter=ContentType/Name eq 'Highlight Report'"` and see it works.

**Update #1:**

Following solution is regarding **CAML** + **C#**

[Filter By ContentType using CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/89852/21421)

Now make it **CAML** + **REST API**

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>
        <Value Type='Computed'>Highlight Report</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

For executing CAML in REST API

**End-Point:**

```
String.format("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{0}')/getitems", documentsListTitle)
```

**HTTP Method:**

```
POST
```

**Request Body:**

```
var query = "<View>" + 
 "<Query>" + 
 "<Where>" + 
 "<Eq>" + 
 "<FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>" + 
 "<Value Type='Computed'>Highlight Report</Value>" + 
 "</Eq>" + 
 "</Where>" + 
 "</Query>" + 
 "</View>";

var data = {
    query: {
        __metadata: {
            'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'
        },
        ViewXml: query
    }
};
```

Let me know for more modification or explanation.

Comment: Yep, it works without the filter but then how do I filter by the name of a content type? Surely there's a way

Comment: did not find any using REST yet. there could way using **CSOM**. If you are dealing with very few items, then filter them in request complete like `success` function

Comment: See my last update @Submits

Comment: ok ...... waiting to hear from you

Comment: Brilliant, it worked. It's a shame you have to use CAML to achieve this though! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `ContentTypeId` as the filter , the example below is returning results for me:

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Reusable%20Content')/items?$select=ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$filter=ContentTypeId%20eq%20%270x01002CF74A4DAE39480396EEA7A4BA2BE5FB009CBCDDE56A142247B896B1DE93CE3843%27
```

**Update 1:**
Filtering on `ContentType` field also works.
Try by replacing the space within the content type name by %20 in your REST Url

```
http://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Reusable%20Content')/items?$select=ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$filter=ContentType%20eq%20%27Reusable%20HTML%27
```

Comment: ContentTypeId is not an option because this site will become a site template and I'm not sure the content type IDs will remain the same.

Comment: You can get the content type Id dynamically by making a request like this: /_api/web/ContentTypes?$select=Name,Id&$filter=Name%20eq%20%27Item%27

Comment: You're right, this could be a solution. The only down side is I would need to make two REST calls.